# Array with nested elements whose properties depend on data property do not reactive vue ts

Tags: typescript, class, vue.js, vue-reactivity

There is the array with nested elements whose properties depend on data properties. Question is: why is not reactive? Set and Get Vue observer sets for this properties. But when data properties change (this.errorData.isNotServerError = true), properties in array with nested elements whose properties rely on data properties is not updated. Typescipt with Vue.

'''
    `private baseErrorLabelList = [
    {
      condition: this.errorData.isNotServerError,
      text: this.$root.$t('login.error_label.not_server_error'),
    },
  ];`
'''

The array is above.

'''
   `private emptyErrorData = {
      isIncorrectDataProvided: false,
      isServerError: false,
      isNotServerError: false,
    };
    private userData = Object.assign({}, this.emptyUserData);
    public errorData = Object.assign({}, this.emptyErrorData);`
'''
The data property.

Even if delete assign, nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just to move baseErrorLabelList property to computed property.